# How to use a wildcard in an if statement?

Tags: php, web

Would it be possible to use a wildcard in an if statement like this?

```
if(trim($line) != $DELETE)
```

Full code:

```
 $DELETE = "*TotalWar";

$data = file("../oneos/applist.txt");

$out = array();

 foreach($data as $line) {
     if(trim($line) != $DELETE) {
         $out[] = $line;
     }
 }

 $fp = fopen("./foo.txt", "w+");
 flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
 foreach($out as $line) {
     fwrite($fp, $line);
 }
 flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
 fclose($fp);
```

I am a complete php noob, but PHP is the only way I see my project working. I need a user to be able to delete a line in a text file, no matter what is infront of the text they enter. For example, if the user enters `delete TotalWar` and the text file looks like this: `set app24=TotalWar`, I need the script to delete the entire line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fnmatch()` for this

`fnmatch()` checks if the passed `string` would match the given shell `wildcard pattern.`

for more info read http://php.net/fnmatch

Comment: Can you give an example?